# Evaluating arguments of Clojure tagged literals

Tags: macros, clojure, literals

I have been trying to use Clojure tagged literals, and noticed that the reader does not evaluate the arguments, very much like a macro. This makes sense, but what is the appropriate solution for doing this? Explicit eval?

Example: given this function

```
(defn my-data
  ([[arg]]
     (prn (symbol? arg))
     :ok))
```

and this definition `data_readers.clj`

```
{myns/my-data my.ns/my-data}
```

The following behave differently:

```
> (let [x 1] (my.ns/my-data [x]))
false
:ok
```

So the `x` passed in is evaluated before being passed into `my-data`. On the other hand:

```
> (let [x 1] #myns/my-data [x])
true
:ok
```

So if I want to use the value of `x` inside `my-data`, the `my-data` function needs to do something about it, namely check that `x` is a symbol, and if so, use `(eval x)`. That seems ugly. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

There is no way to get at the value of the local `x` in your example, primarily because locals only get assigned values at runtime, whereas tagged literals are handled at read time. (There's also compile time in between; it is impossible to get at locals' values at compile time; therefore macros cannot get at locals' values either.)<sup>1</sup>

**The better approach is to use a regular function at runtime**, since after all you want to construct a value based on the runtime values of some parameters. Tagged literals really are *literals* and should be used as such.

#### Extended discussion

To illustrate the issue described above:

```
(binding [*data-readers* {'bar (fn [_] (java.util.Date.))}]
  (eval (read-string "(defn foo [] #bar x)")))
```

`foo` will always return the same value, because the reader has only one opportunity to return a value for `#bar x` which is then baked into `foo`'s bytecode.

Notice also that instead of passing it to `eval` directly, we could store the data structure returned by the call to `read-string` and compile it at an arbitrary point in the future; the value returned by `foo` would remain the same. Clearly there's no way for such a literal value to depend on the future values of any locals; in fact, during the reader's operation, it is not even clear which symbols will come to name locals -- that's for the compiler to determine and the result of that determination may be non-obvious in cases where macros are involved.

Of course the reader is free to return a form which looks like a function call, the name of a local etc. To show one example:

```
(binding [*data-readers* {'bar (fn [sym] (list sym 1 2 3 4 5))}]
  (eval (read-string "#bar *")))
;= 120
;; substituting + for * in the string yields a value of 15
```

Here `#bar f` becomes equivalent to `(f 1 2 3 4 5)`. Needless to say, this is an abuse of notation and doesn't really do what you asked for.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's worth pointing out that `eval` has no access to locals (it always operates in the global scope), but the issue with locals not having values assigned before runtime is more fundamental.